# Populating an empty div on a page with a specific body class

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm trying to write some JS that will look for a specific body class and replace the empty content found on the page with a chunk of HTML.

In other words, I'd like the JS to trigger on a page that has the body class of "ly_productdetails ProductDetails en en_GB" and inject some specific HTML.

I'm a JS noob so not really sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      if ($('body.ly_productdetails ProductDetails en     en_GB').length > 0) {
        var element = document.getElementById("container");
        element.innerHTML = "<div><h1>Products</h1></div>";
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/du5rtfw7/

Any tips would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Check the second example for how to make jquery selectors with several classes http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Comment: if you are wanting it to be the body with all of those classes the selector should be `body.ly_productdetails.ProductDetails.en.en_GB` the spaces mean any element with a class of `en_GB` within an element with a class of `en` within `ProductDetails` within `body.ly_productdetails` - http://jsfiddle.net/du5rtfw7/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ly_productdetails`, `ProductDetails`, `en`, `en_GB` are all class names, you should do: `body.ly_productdetails.ProductDetails.en.en_GB`.

BTW, you can do this without jQuery:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  if (document.querySelector("body.ly_productdetails.ProductDetails.en.en_GB")) {
    var element = document.getElementById("container");
    element.innerHTML = "<div><h1>Products</h1></div>";
  }
}
```

(Edit) Okay, jQuery version:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("body.ly_productdetails.ProductDetails.en.en_GB").length > 0) {
    var element = document.getElementById("container");
    element.innerHTML = "<div><h1>Products</h1></div>";
  }
}
```

Comment: Though I think it's better to demonstrate it with jQuery. If he's green, putting in native functions will just confuse.

Comment: @ViktorCarlén Oh, I agree and just added jQuery version too. :D

Comment: The dots did the trick. Thanks (and yes, very green at the moment)

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
$(function(){
    if ($('body.ly_productdetails.ProductDetails.en.en_GB').length > 0) {
        $('#container').html('<div><h1>Products</h1></div>');
    }
});
```

You simply used wrong CSS query..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to check if `#container` is empty, do it using `.is(':empty')` in jQuery:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class="ly_productdetails ProductDetails en en_GB">
  <div id="container"></div>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      if ($('body.ly_productdetails.ProductDetails.en.en_GB').length > 0) {
        if ($('div#container').is(':empty')) {
          $('div#container').html("<div><h1>Products</h1></div>");
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
  <p>Empty container gets populated</p>
</body>
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/du5rtfw7/3/)

*Readup:*

- [.is() | jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/is/)
- [:empty Selector | jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/)
- [.html() | jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Answer (score 0):

You have a few really good answers, I'll just chip in and say a match function is what I would prefer to use (For its speed).

```
$(function() {    // document ready
    var body = $(document.body);    // body element

    // If match and length then modify html
    if (body.attr('class').match(/ly_productdetails ProductDetails en en_GB/).length > 0) {
        $('#container').html("<div><h1>Products</h1></div>");
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/34svmabn/

Speed Test: http://jsperf.com/hasclass-vs-is-stackoverflow/7

Comment: That's interesting. So using 'match' will be be better from a performance perspective? Thanks